# Check if click event originated by button inside tr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html table with 5 columns. In one column i have a button.
When i click on the row, with jquery i apply a css on the row (i selected the row). But when i click on the button on that row i don't want apply the style to the row.

Now i check if i click on the row like this:

```
$('#mytable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {

    //If the click originated by the button don't apply stile
    //...

    //...else apply the style on tr

}
```

Inside the function how can i check if the click is originated by the button?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `target` property of the event to determine the element which raised the event that bubbled. Try this:

```
$('#mytable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BUTTON') {
        // the button was clicked...
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could use `stopPropagation` on the button click:

```
$('#mytable tbody').on('click', 'button', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // other logic...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `event.stopPropagation()`  inside your button click

> **event.stopPropagation()**
>   Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

source : https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

You can check your current target using `event.currenttarget`and apply the style.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter that via `event.target`:

```
$('#mytable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName != 'TR') return;

  // handle event
});
```

If you have a jQuery event handler on the button, use `event.stopPropagation` so the `click` event does not bubble up the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

1. assign a `className` or `id` to the `button`.
2. use `event.target.className` to check if the originating element contained the `className` or `id` you gave your `button`. Only fire the `tr` event function to style your `tr` when the event origination is not from the button (when it is equal to the button class then stop)

```
if(event.target.className===<className>) {
     //exit the function
    return
} else {
    //do the styling
}
```